# Proxy any request over a ws socket using plain javascript

Tags: javascript, browser, websocket, client-side

I want to proxy any possible request from a webpage using a websocket connection.

I've resolved this in ajax environment implementing a custom XHRHttpRequest.
For each link I remove the href destination (or set it to '#') and set an onclick event.

What can I do with the img tags?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Nothing.

By the time your javascript executes, probably the `IMG.src` resolution is already in course.

You may add the `src` as `data-src` instead and then have some javascript code that either set the `src` attribute or get the image through the websocket.

But, why are you doing this? Request multiplexing is part of the HTTP2 spec. You should stick to common HTTP1.x practices for the moment like bundling CSS and JS, image sprite, image compression, leveraging HTTP caching, etc.. etc... Doing something like that you are going to get into big complexity.

Comment: I want to implement a pseudo browser in javascript that delegates any http request to the wss server. In this way I want to implement a kind of HTTP proxy where each request is redirected using the websocket.

Comment: It won't work with IMG, IFRAME, SCRIPT, etc... Neither with embedded CSS and CSS itself.